# Scale down model of a refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics

I am teaching Thermodynamics. For teaching how refrigerators work I am looking for a working model of a scale down refrigerator. This should be as close to real as possible but very small in size. Can someone help me in locating one? Google is not helping me in finding.

If not then at least I would like to know other closely matching models which can be used for demonstrating various things in thermodynamics.

Comment: Why do you want it to be (very) small? For not a lot of money you can get a real, working (but "portable") fridge - of the conventional compressor type. In the US they are known as "campus fridges" and retail for around $80. It allows you to hook up thermocouples, measure power used, determine heat flow (quality of insulation), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find more useful material by rather looking for "heat pumps" instead of refrigerators. If you teach them about the basic ideas of thermodynamics used in a heat pump first, understanding refrigerators becomes trivial.

Three useful links that I just found:

[Physics of heat pump](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/heatpump.html)

[How heat pump works](http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/how-heat-pumps-work.html)

[The basic physics of heat pumps](http://physics777.tripod.com/physics/Alevel/basic%20physics%20of%20heat%20pumps.pdf)